# Setting USB Device name in STM32CubeMX generated USB project

Tags: embedded, usb, microcontroller, stm32

I want to communicate my product string to Windows so that the STM32 device doesn't show as a 'USB Input Device' under the device manager. Is this information derived from the PID/VID, or is there a way for me to communicate a custom product string?

Comment: You need to write the ing file as well

Answer (score 0):

The device itself has various identifications including vendor strings and the VID/PID. You will see these in Device Manager while the device is "unknown" and Windows searches for a driver.

However when Windows matches the VID/PID to a device driver, it uses the strings in the associated driver .ini file rather than those provided by the device.

For a signed driver however, modifying the INI file is not possible with out re-singing it, and Windows will not normally allow unsigned drivers.  Moreover recently in Windows 10, drivers must be approved and signed by Microsoft; and you still need your own EV certificate in order to submit your driver for approval.  Obtaining your own VID and EV code signing certificate are not free, and testing of drivers for Windows qualification is not straightforward, and service providers to do that for you are expensive too.

Comment: You can allow installation of unsigned drivers

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm aware as much about EV certification for drivers, and VID for USB. We've been designing a product that makes use of STM32 devices, and are planning to ask them to sub-license their VID/PID for the device we use. 

In a prototype version, we had a fake VID/PID assigned, and had our device listed by the product name, as opposed to a generic 'USB Input Device' under HID. That developer has since become inactive, and we were looking to do the same with the use of the VID/PID provided by STMicroelectronics.

Comment: @P__J__ : Of course - as a developer, but it is not really suitable for distribution.  Not if you want to look professional.